# I have an XML script ,How do I write a query in Xpath?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I have an XML script ,How do I write a query in Xpath? The query Should bring the students name that has the average course grade above 70?

XML

```
<Students>
    <student StudentID="12">
        <StudentName>Ruti Dohan</StudentName>
        <CourseID>49001</CourseID>
        <Grade>100</Grade>
    </student>
    <student StudentID ="13">
        <StudentName >Lola Tomas</StudentName>
        <CourseID>77301</CourseID>
        <Grade>90</Grade>
    </student>
    <student StudentID ="14">
        <StudentName>Lola Tomas</StudentName>
        <CourseID>49001</CourseID>
        <Grade>55</Grade>
    </student>
    <student StudentID ="15">
        <StudentName>Reli Mitai</StudentName>
        <CourseID>77301</CourseID>
        <Grade>80</Grade>
    </student>
</Students>
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? And please share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath expression should get you there:

```
//student[Grade>70]/StudentName
```

Output:

```
Ruti Dohan
Lola Tomas
Reli Mitai
```